# RTRIM function trim extra character

Tags: oracle, function

```
SELECT RTRIM('CO_CODE_VALUE', 'VALUE') FROM dual;
```

Result is CO_CODE_
But

```
SELECT RTRIM('CO_CODE_VALUE', '_VALUE') FROM dual;
```

Result is CO_COD

Does anybody know why?

Comment: To remove a **string** from the end of another string, use `SUBSTR`, e.g. https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f809pzcu91yyfs0ni8p6udsbi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/RTRIM.html#GUID-95A7DAFB-F7AB-48F4-BE24-64B3C7A840AA):

> RTRIM removes from the right end of char all of the characters that
>   appear in set.

That is, in your case, it starts from the right and removes all the characters in the **set** '_VALUE', not the **string** '_VALUE'.
For example:

```
select rtrim('EEEXEEEEEEE', '_VALUE') from dual
```

gives

```
EEEX
```

Because it starts from the right, and removes all the characters in `('V', 'A', 'L', 'U', 'E', 'S', '_')`, that is all the occurences of `'E'` going backward until it finds a character not in the set (the `'X'`)